# Eigenvalues of truncated correlation matrix

Tags: condensed-matter, entropy, quantum-entanglement

Take a Fermionic gapped 1-D lattice Hamiltonian $H=\sum_{ij}t_{ij}c^\dagger_ic_j$ with periodic boundary as an example, and we bipartite it into two subsystems $A$ and $B$, and the eigenvalues of the truncated correlation matrix $C_A$ of the half-filled ground state $|\Omega\rangle$ is bounded in between $0$ and $1$, where the matrix elements of $C_A$ is $(C_A)_{ij}=\langle\Omega|c^\dagger_{i\in A} c_{j\in A}|\Omega\rangle$.

Does there exist a physics interpretation or mathematical proof of this property that eigenvalues of $C_A$ must lie in $[0,1]$? Or does this have a connection with Gaussian states?

Reference: [Entanglement entropy and the Berry phase in solid states](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0601237v3)

Comment: Fermions? Bosons? Something else? For fermions, this basically amounts to the uncertainty principle. But you will have to add some details for the question to make sense, and for being able to provide a succinct answer.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Did you mean to say "Pauli Principle" instead?

Comment: @TobiasFünke No. The correlation matrix I have in mind contains correlations in 2nd quantization, e.g. $\langle a_i^\dagger a_j\rangle$, or the like (symmetrized versions, Majorana basis, etc.). The non-trivial commutator of these operators constrains the possible values such a matrix can take. Or, if you wish, if you transform to a diagonal basis (or simply consider a single mode), it relates to the fact that $0\le\langle a^\dagger a\rangle\le1$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your analysis, but this is Pauli's principle (and not Heisenberg's uncertainty). Well, OK, one might argue what exactly PP is, but to me it is fully captured in the fermionic anti-commutation relations.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I would have said the Pauli principle is the antisymmetry of the wavefunction. But yes, one can argue about that. One more reason to prefer formulas over names. -- The uncertainty relation is certainly something which stems directly from the anticommutators, and in the Majorana basis, this basically amounts to inequalities relating $\langle p q\rangle$, $\langle p^2$, and $\rangle q^2$, which is basically an uncertainty relation.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes fermions and I've just editted it. But could you please help me to understand why the uncertainty principle necessarily constrains the eigenvalues of $C_A$? To my knowledge, the matrix elements of $C_A$ does not have a direct connection with its eigenvalues.

Comment: Let $C(f,g):=\langle \psi, a^\dagger(g)a(f)\psi\rangle$, where $f,g$ are single-particle states, $\psi$ is a many-body (fermionic) state and the ladder operators obey the canonical anti-commutation relations $\{a(f),a^\dagger(g)\}=1 \langle f,g\rangle$. Now it holds, in the sense of operators, that $0\leq C \leq 1$, which means that for all single-particle states $f$ it holds that $0\leq C(f,f)\leq \langle f,f\rangle$. In particular, this implies that all eigenvalues of $C$ are in $[0,1]$; this follows because the above inequalities in particular hold for the (normalized) eigenstates of $C$.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Seems this statement only proved eigenvalues of $C$ are in $[0,1]$ rather not the truncated one $C_A$, since an eigenstate of $C_A$ is not an eigenstate of $C$?

Comment: @user835469 I don't understand. Why can't you apply my previous comment to $C_A$ at all?